# android app published, but not found in google play

Tags: android, google-play

I published my app at 14-04-2014 on playstore. But I didn't find it on playstore. And when I tried following solution to find that.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourpackagename 
and status of app is "published" and "in Prod"

Comment: can you share package name?

Comment: my package name: vn.pp.block.minion

Comment: go to your app detail in the developer console, near the title you will see "View in Google Play store" click on it. It will direct you to your app. and make sure that your package name is ` vn.pp.block.minion` in your manifest.

Comment: yes, i', sure my package name in code is "vn.pp.block.minion"

Comment: Has it been over 24 hours since it showed as published?

Comment: I published my app at 14-04-2014, 2 day ago

Answer (score 9):

You may have incorrect package name as your application is already published.

The package name is defined in your android manifest file as -

```
package="yourpackagename"
```

Make sure that for your application, it is defined as--

```
 package="vn.pp.block.minion"
```

Then you can use ---

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vn.pp.block.minion

**UPDATE:**

If after confirmation you still believe that your application package name is correct when you use it to find at google play store then just use the following --

[Google Play Android Developer TroubleShooter](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055196?hl=en).

**UPDATE:**

If the troubleshooter can't help either then you can directly take help by letting them know about your issue. Just go to the below link to register the issue --

[Application Missing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing?extra.IssueType=missing).

As mentioned,

> Support Team will reply by email within 2 business days.

Good Luck!

Comment: Obviously I can click but it can't take me to your released app. Check my updated answer and use troubleshooter provided by Google Store itself.

Comment: thanks for support, i trying troubleshooter. and now wait for Google Store :) "Thank you for contacting us. Please note, we do our best to reply within 2 business days. However, some issues can take longer to respond. We appreciate your patience while we investigate your report"

Comment: Kudos. As you are new to SO and haven't accepted any answer yet. So if you finds any answer fit to what you wanted then you can click on tick mark that is on left of that answer to accept that answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

After submitting an app to the Play store, an app isn’t shown instantly in play store.  It will take around max 24 hours to update in the play store, sometimes it will update soon like within an hour. So we have to check after some time like 2 or 3 hours it will update.

**A reason for the delay:**  After submitting our apps, google play store authority verifies our app. So, this can take time for that. Google Play Store authority verify our app file for malware or adware file. So, for the sake of users, they take time for that.

**Solution:**

**1)** In addition to the time it takes for app updates to fully process, the Google Play app itself also caches app information, so maybe we seeing a cached version of your Google Play store.

Here's a trick to force Google Play to fetch the latest version of your app. Go to phone's settings and cleared the play stores cache. The Google Play app's cache should now be reset. Try finding your app again and see if it shows the latest version.

We can also take help from Google team: here is link for that

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en

**2)** A final solution, Publishing the App with new version code and name.

Answer (score 1):

Without good number of downloads, the app won't be visible for its search terms or even its full name. However you can directly access the app by its unique URL at any time. Unique URL will be

`"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+packageName`

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps -

1. Replace 'packagename' with your package's name in the URL https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=packagename
2. Now download from this [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xxxx) and install it
3. Then comment your app on the Play Store, then search again, and you will find it this time.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and nothing of the above or from the trouble shooter fixed it.

The problem seemed to be because of the chrome history, since i clicked the link before 24H passed and after it the link still didn't work.

Login in incognito window or clean your history and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the device you are trying to download the app to doesn't meet that apps hardware requirements.

***http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tablets.html#hardware-requirements***