# Android app visibility and searchability issue after packagename and title were changed

Tags: android, search, google-play, google-play-services, package-name

So we had an android app earlier with packagename

> **app.myapp.company**

format 
which we wanted to change to

> **com.mycompany.myapp**

So we created a new app with changed package name and changed the app title
From

> **mygreatapp -  app for people**

to

> **mygreatapp -  app for people :)**
>    (as you cant have same title for 2 apps)

and uploaded it as a fresh new app to Play Store and unpublished the old app.

**Observations:**

Its been 24 hours since the new app has been uploaded
In dev console.
The new app is shown as  "published"
The old app is shown as "unpublished"

**Issues:**

New users searching for our app on the playstore are still not able to find the new app.
There are no search results for "mygreatapp" for them
Old users who had the app installed on their devices, first uninstalled/ cleaned cache the old app
But still they are seeing the old app on playstore i.e.
"mygreatapp -  app for people" instead of the new app below.
"mygreatapp -  app for people :)"

We have checked all setings etc and all looks fine.
So, how do I make the old app dissapear and new app appear on play store.

I have already read the posts below but did not resolve the issue.

[android app published, but not found in google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108684/android-app-published-but-not-found-in-google-play).

Please help

Comment: The package name is used as ID in the PlayStore. So if you change it for a new App, you have to create a whole new App in the DevConsole. So remove the old App and create a whole new one. That's it.

Comment: Yes @Baschi i had to do the same. Google does not allow change of packagename for published apps.  It rejects the upload if you try to upload an app update with packagename changed.  You have to create a complete new app

Comment: Ok, fine. Then its just the search engine, which might take some more time then 24hours. Can you access your new App using such a link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompany.myapp?? If so, all is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it working somehow.

thinking it could be a indexing issue with google.
I renamed the old app to "xyz" and then within 2-3 hours the new app was found in searches