# How to find my uploaded application on google play

Tags: flutter, google-play

I have published my application 8 days ago on Google Play and I can't see it on google play when I search but when I copy the whole link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=player.one1987 ,I find it on Play Store.

note: when i search by application Id (player.one1987) i find my app but when i 
search by application title(player one) i cant see it, can anyone please tell me?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9042516?hl=en) helps.

Comment: not help me @Christian

Answer (score 1):

From [android app published, but not found in google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23108684/android-app-published-but-not-found-in-google-play)

> If you are a developer and have just released your app, it can happen because Google Play needs some time to index your app to add it to search results. Try to search your app later (in 4-5 hours). E.g., for App Store it takes around 24 hours
>
> You should do something related to ASO (App Store Optimization) to improve the visibility of your app (use keywords that your app relates to).

Answer (score 0):

If you see it by direct link that means your app is up and available. About the Play Store search, your app is just a new app on Play Store. According to an article more than 100 apps uploaded on the Play Store every day. Buy when you search Play Store gives priority to the apps with most download and most reviews first. Also your keyword are pretty common to search.

You have to wait for some time and promote your app from your available channels. You can optimise your app content as per this guide (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en).

When I created my app `Easy Html` I was facing this issue but slowly and steadily I optimise the content and other details. And now my application come first if you put the exact name. You can search for more optimization techniques if you google it.